# override method from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a website in my solution and a Data Class project
data class is referenced to website
now i want override method a from data class to web site
i think this is possible because after compile data class is a dll in website

my data class :

```
public partial class forInherit
{
    public virtual int getUserID()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public partial class logFunctions : forInherit
{
}
```

and my web site :

```
public partial class logFunctions
{
    public override int getUserID()
    {
    }
}
```

but my error is

**no suitable method found to override**

Comment: Partial is used to split between source files, not between projects

Answer (score 2):

Partial class definitions only define the same class if the namespace of the partial class definitions is the same and they are defined in the same assembly.
Both criteria are not fulfilled in your case.

If I understand your intent correctly, you want to give consumers of your data classes the possibility to change the behavior of the `getUserID()` method while still using the class `logFunctions` from your data class project.

You can achieve this by several means, one very simple would be to give `logFunctions` a delegate that is called when `getUserID()` is called. Another possibility would be to introduce an interface that is passed to `logFunctions`.

Example for the first option:

In your data project:

```
public class forInherit
{
    public virtual int getUserID()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class logFunctions : forInherit
{
    public Func<int> GetUserIDDelegate { get; set; }

    public override int getUserID()
    {
        if(GetUserIDDelegate == null)
            return 0;
        return GetUserIDDelegate();
    }
}
```

In your web project:

```
logFunctionsInstance.GetUserIDDelegate = () => { return 1; };
```

Comment: i want use a property value in my website to my data class.Indeed i can't access this property in my data class.so i want do  it override in web site to return property value

Answer (score 0):

The `logFunction` class in your web site needs to inherit the `forInherit` class in you data class project.

While both your `logFunction` classes are `partial` they are in different projects, and probably namespaces (you don't specify.) So, both are related only by name and not by the compiler.